# Dynamic padding based on Window Size and Max-Width of Container

Tags: css

I have a `container` class which has following styles:

```
.container {
   width: 90%;
   max-width: 1400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I also have a custom carousel which has following css:

```
.carousel {
   display: flex;
   padding-left: 5vw;
}
```

Now, what I want is the content inside `container` and the content inside the `carousel` should start from left at the same position. The `padding-left:5vw` works fine until the screen size crosses `1400px`.

And I can't put `carousel` inside `container` because the `carousel` should have full-width of the screen.

Now I need help to make a calculation for `padding-left`, so that it works with `width: 90%` and `max-width: 1400px`

Answer (score 0):

Yiu can use media queries and when width of screen reach 1400 do something like that

```
@media (max-width:1400px){
.carousel{
 padding-left: calc((100% - 1400px) / 2)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I wanted to do it without media query

Comment: @Shuvo you can watch container width in JS, but why media bed? I dont think you have another way to achieve that

Comment: Well, I am thinking of something like that:
`calc(12px + (12.8 - 12) * ((100vw - 320px) / (1750 - 320)));`

This is a calculation for Fluid `font-size`. I was actually looking for something like that.